# Refund of visa application fee

Tags: nigerian-citizens

I was trying to filled a Uk APPLICATION on the 6th December,2018,When i was filling my Uk application form online,i discovered i made a mistake and there is no means to correct mistake after payment stage,so i decided to cancel the application and fill a form for refund and after completed the refund form, i got a message that it will be refunded in the next 28 days.so i filled another application and made another payment, but up till now i did not receive the refund for the application that i cancel in my card .Please what can i do?